# Downgrading from Anaconda Python 3.6 to Python 3.5.2 Not Working

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, anaconda, python-3.5

I am trying to downgrade python to 3.5.2 so I can run TensorFlow. Running into a bit of an issue here, not sure why. I open my cmd and run `python` - shows me Python 3.6.1 is running. Exit() out of cmd, then type `conda install python=3.5.2`. It shows that 3.5.2 is currently installed, but for whatever reason when I'm in cmd and `python` it keeps showing my that python is in verison 3.6. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `echo $PATH`.  What does it say?  `which python`.  What does it say?

Comment: Also, FWIW, I recently installed tensorflow 1.1 from source into a python3.6 environment that I had set up.  Everything worked fine on my macbook  (OS-X 10.11.6) -- Of course, I wasn't doing anything fancy with the GPU, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using anaconda, a better idea would be to start a new environment rather than trying to install a new python in an *old* environment.  That's basically asking for the same set of problems that virtual environments are made to circumvent ;-)

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5.2
source activate py35
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!